# Will GLSL compiler remove unnecessary variable initialization?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

For example, I have a code like this (fragment shader):

## Option 1

```
#version 330 core

uniform sampler2D baseImage;
in vec2 texCoord;
out vec3 fragColor;

void main() {
    fragColor = texture(baseImage, texCoord).rgb;

    // some calculations that don't use fragColor
    vec3 calcResult = ...

    fragColor = calcResult;
}
```

Will compiler remove `fragColor = texture(baseImage, texCoord).rgb`?

## Option 2

```
#version 330 core

uniform sampler2D baseImage;
in vec2 texCoord;
out vec3 fragColor;

void init0() {
    fragColor = texture(baseImage, texCoord).rgb;
}

void init1() {
    fragColor = texture(baseImage, texCoord).rgb;
}

void main() {
    init0();
    init1();
}
```

Will compiler use code from `init1()`?

Comment: What the compiler has to optimize is not specified in the [specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#changes). The glsl shader code is compiled by the graphics driver (except you generate [SPIR-V](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/SPIR-V)). But a modern graphics driver will do such optimizations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the compiler has to optimize is not specified in the [specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#changes).
The only thing what is specified is the behavior of active program resources. See [OpenGL 4.6 Core Profile Specification - 7.3.1 Program Interfaces](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf#page=124&zoom=100,0,173), page 102.

The glsl shader code is compiled by the graphics driver (except you generate [SPIR-V](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/SPIR-V)), so it depends on. But a modern graphics driver will do such optimizations.

By default optimizations are switched on, but they can be switched off by

```c
#pragma optimize(off)
```

See [OpenGL Shading Language 4.60 Specification - 3.3. Preprocessor](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#preprocessor)